# How to speed up this read in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am have a task that needed to search a movie. I would like to get every frame from the movie and do what I want, as shown in the following code.

```
videoObject = VideoReader(fileName);
numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
frameRate = videoObject.FrameRate;

for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames
    thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);     

    %% Here I do what I need
end
```

Then I found that I can pick every 10 frames and still do what I want. So I changed the code like this.

```
videoObject = VideoReader(fileName);
numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
frameRate = videoObject.FrameRate;

for frame = 1 : 10 : numberOfFrames
    thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);     

    %% Here I do what I need
end
```

But I found that the time spent by the second version is very long. I measure the time spent like this.

```
videoObject = VideoReader(fileName);
numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
frameRate = videoObject.FrameRate;

tic
for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames
    thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);     

    if(mod(frame, 100) == 1)
        toc
        tic
    end
    %% Here I do what I need
end
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 0.049704 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.180742 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.220797 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.188777 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.238565 seconds.
```

I do the same thing to the second version and get

```
Elapsed time is 0.018620 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.982572 seconds.
Elapsed time is 15.634653 seconds.
Elapsed time is 24.626017 seconds.
Elapsed time is 5.307010 seconds.
Elapsed time is 14.970220 seconds.
Elapsed time is 24.230995 seconds.
```

The speed is very strange and also for the same 100 frames it takes much more time. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be in a [Shlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) situation: it looks like each call to `read()` is reading all the frames up to the one you specify. Which makes sense, because most movie file formats are not random access. Instead they encode occasional key frames and then a series of deltas to that key frame.

The one where you're striding by 10 takes longer on each pass because it has to read 10 times as many frames on each call.

It looks like the `read` method is designed more to take a list of frame indexes. Since you know the indexes of all the frames you want to get, you can replace it with a single call to read.

```
allFrames = read(videoObject, 1:10:numberOfFrames)
```

Or switch to the `readFrame` method, which will allow you to grab frames sequentially while maintaining a placeholder in `videoObject`'s state. The [help for `VideoObject.read`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) says `read` is deprecated in favor of `readFrame`, anyway.

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment. Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab